# Routing is not working with self-hosted web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing, asp.net-core-2.1

This is essentially what I have, a very simple set of three files with fresh asp.net core 2.1 (actually copy-pasted from tutorials):

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

Then goes the simplest startup

```
class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

And default values controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

No matter what I call I see in console same 404 error:

```
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/values
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 105.0181ms 404
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/api/values
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 2.6016ms 404
etc
```

I tried adding default route both with `app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();` and specifying it manually. I tried removing route attributes when used the default route. Also tried adding `AddControllersAsServices()`. But result is still same - 404. When I setup custom handler in `app.Run` then it works without any issues.

---

csproj (I have replaced default Microsoft.AspNetCore.All dependency, but routing still does not work)

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This was rather difficult to track down, but the problem boils down to this in your .csproj:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

As you are building a web application, you need to instead reference the Web Sdk, as follows:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

I managed to reproduce and fix your issue with this small change.

Answer (score 11):

For me it helped adding `AddApplicationPart` after `AddMvc` like this:

```
.AddMvc()
.AddApplicationPart(typeof(Startup).Assembly)
```

Comment: I am curious. As per documentation(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts?view=aspnetcore-3.0), what I understand is that you use  AddApplicationPart() to reuse controllers, razor pages etc. from other assemblies, isn't it? Why do you need to use this for controllers in the same assembly. Can you please explain?

Comment: Interestingly, calling this method was only necessary on my linux machine (Ubuntu 18.04). Under windows, the controllers were found automatically.

Comment: This has saved me! I would also be interested in an explanation as to why it is needed...

Answer (score 1):

you can try change code to this:

```
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/values")]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

The atribute Route can use for asigning an specific route to a function on api or view.

then to call you can use:

'localhost:5000/api/values'

Comment: Sorry, tried both specifying route in `HttGet`, in separate `Route` attribute and removing all attributes with default routing - same story