# Controllers are not found in ASP.NET core in console application

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to get a a simple asp.net core projection set with just a basic configuration and a controller working but no avail so far. I did use the code from the web template project to create a new console project but no controllers are found.

Here is what the project looks like so far:

[image: Project structure]

[image: Console output]

[image: Route not found]

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}

[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Test")]
    public ActionResult<string> Get()
    {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}

//appsettings.json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I'm missing something very obvious here but can't figure it out, any help is welcome.

Thanks

*UPDATE 1*

[image: As per comment, trying http://localhost:5000/test/get]

*UPDATE 2*

[image: As per Damir's comment]

Comment: Shouldn't the route by 'api/test' ?

Comment: @MarcusHöglund I don't think so my friend because I am specifying the route at the action level, but I gave it a try anyway, just in case the behavior i. core was different, but I get the same result. Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Routing is not working with self-hosted web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50632468/routing-is-not-working-with-self-hosted-web-api)

Answer (score 3):

@marco

just add Route to your controller, it should be like

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Test")]
    public ActionResult<string> Get()
    {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

and url will look like: 
https://localhost:5001/api/test/test

*UPDATE:*

added screenshot

[image]

Comment: Is it mandatory now to have a route configured at the class level? I am asking because this was not the web api 2 behavior. I will give it a try, thanks Damir.

Comment: I gave it a try but it isn't working either. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: make double-check based on my recently added screenshot, it should work anyway if you doing the same. don't forget build your app. You can use the next cli commands - `dotnet build` + `dotnet run`

Comment: it turned out to be a problem with one of the dependencies, thanks a lot anyway  mate.

Comment: BTW, adding a `[Route]` attribute to the controller is a good practice for api apps, moreover, aspnet.core template is adding this attribute by default during creating Asp.net Core Web API project

Comment: Yes I follow that practice but this was just a test, but thanks a lot for pointing that out though :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't pay attention but I had a warning in one of the dependencies and after adding them again, I got my original code working, thanks guys.

[image: Added dependencies]